# Problems with this C code

Tags: c

I build a C code to apply automatically D'Hondt Law. So I did it on C language, using NetBeans 8.0.2. I am trying to compile it (having no errors) and it gives this message `RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 4s)`. I checked it a lot of times without result, that's why I am asking here. I'd apprecciate some help. **SOLVED**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int LerDeputados() {
    int d;
    printf("Indique o número de deputados a repartir: ");
    scanf("%d",&d);    
    return d;
}

int LerPartidos() {
    int n;
    printf("Introduza o número de partidos: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    return n;
}

int main(void) {
    int d, n, i, k, m, j, z, x, aleatorio, b, dip[1000];
    float e[1000][1000], maximo[1000], v[1000];
    d= LerDeputados();
    n= LerPartidos();

    srand(time(NULL));
    aleatorio=rand();

    do{
        i++;
        printf("Número de votos do %dº partido: ",i);
        scanf("%f",&v[i]);       
    }while(i<n);

    for(j=1;j<=d;j++){
        for(k=1;k<=i;k++){
            e[j][k]=v[k]/j;
        }         
    }
    for(x=1;x<=n;x++) {
        dip[x]=0;
    }

    for(m=1;m<=d;m++){
        maximo[m]=0;
        for (j=1;j<=d;j++) {
            for (k=1;k<=i;k++) {
                if (e[j][k]>maximo[m]) {
                    maximo[m] = e[j][k];
                    z=j;
                    x=k; 

                }
                else if (maximo[m]==e[j][k]) {
                    if(v[k]>v[x]) {
                        maximo[m] = e[j][k];
                        z=j;
                        x=k; 
                    }
                    else if(v[k]<v[x]) {                        
                    }
                    else {
                        if(aleatorio%2==0){
                            maximo[m] = e[j][k];
                            z=j;
                            x=k;                           
                        }
                    }
                }    
            }
        }
        dip[x]=dip[x]+1;
        e[z][x]=0;                     
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(b=1;b<=n;b++) {
        printf("\nO partido %d acadou %d diputados.",b,dip[b]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And how can I implement this code as a function that works on main?

```
 for(m=1;m<=d;m++){
        maximo[m]=0;
        for (j=1;j<=d;j++) {
            for (k=1;k<=i;k++) {
                if (e[j][k]>maximo[m]) {
                    maximo[m] = e[j][k];
                    z=j;
                    x=k; 

                }
                else if (maximo[m]==e[j][k]) {
                    if(v[k]>v[x]) {
                        maximo[m] = e[j][k];
                        z=j;
                        x=k; 
                    }
                    else if(v[k]<v[x]) {                        
                    }
                    else {
                        if(aleatorio%2==0){
                            maximo[m] = e[j][k];
                            z=j;
                            x=k;                           
                        }
                    }
                }    
            }
        }
        dip[x]=dip[x]+1;
        e[z][x]=0;                     
    }
```

Comment: What if you run it as compiled executable? Anyway, you are allocating *very* large arrays on stack here, which might just overflow the allowed stack size.

Comment: I changed them to 100, and now it works :D. How do I put to enlarge the string in function of how many are needed?

Comment: Some news: google about "debugger". And you can even use `printf` to print intermediate results.

Comment: Either declare these arrays as global, or as `static` or allocate them dynamically (which might fail as well).

Comment: @EugeneSh.: `static` actually **is** global (well, the C standard does not use this term in this context). You might think about external vs. internal linkage.

Comment: Please do not deface your own questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

First, you have some very large arrays in main, which are allocated on the stack.  This can cause issues with stack overflow.

Either declare these large arrays as globals, or allocate them dynamically using `malloc`.

The second issue is that `i` is not initialized when entering the first `do...while` loop.   This value could be anything, so it could result in indexing off the end of the array `v`, leading to undefined behavior.  This is what caused your program to crash.  The fact that it didn't crash after changing the size of the arrays was luck.  Any other change to the code could cause the crash to resurface.

Set `i` to 0 and you should be fine.

```
i=0;
do{
    i++;
    printf("Número de votos do %dº partido: ",i);
    scanf("%f",&v[i]);
}while(i<n);
```

EDIT:

Regarding making the block of code you mentioned a function, move any variables defined in `main` that are used ONLY in this block to the function, and pass in the remaining parameters that `main` uses.

Comment: @PepePérez Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.